# Can we file our CV's on careers to be visible-only-from-SO and get, say, 2 years for $29?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I'm not sure exactly why a promotional-pricing model has been chosen to *target developers* registering their CV's on careers! After all, promotional-pricing is there to encourage me to use the service but I'm hardly likely to resign to take advantage of it!

How about a *"I'm not currently looking for a job"* option, which would mean that:

- you get the promotional rate (maybe for only 2 years)
- your CV is navigable from SO but not searchable on [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) itself, *so it doesn't clutter the employers' results*

This has a few advantages:

1. you get more cash now from people like me (i.e. idiots)
2. you can analyze SO usage patterns to guess when someone has lost their job (or is bored at work?) and send the occasional email saying "Do you want to activate your CV yet?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I'm hardly likely to resign to take advantage of it!

Sometimes I [doubt your commitment to Sparkle Motion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouFnQTq6gNQ).

But seriously …

We're about to launch a free public CV option which I think will cover you. The only reason to pay the $29 is if there is *any* possibility you'll be looking for work in the next 3 years -- so you can flip the "hey make me searchable by employers" toggle.